# Why left Altr key is not working in Ubuntu?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I am curious about that, When we use KaGaPa keyboard layout (and same other layouts) for Devanagari देवनागरी typing there is some problems we face like there is no proper work with Left Alt but same time Right Alt is work fine.
And any other Debian based operating system like BOSS Linux have no issues with left Alt key but Ubuntu something different.
Is it any thing special in Ubuntu with left Alt key?
**ex. you can not type अ with left alter.**

Comment: What do you mean when you say that <Left Alt> doesn't work properly? I just tried _Hindi (KaGaPa phonetic)_ and could successfully open a terminal window by pressing <Ctrl>+<Left Alt>+T. (Please note that it's not supposed to work as <Right Alt>. The latter is dedicated for accessing level 3 and 4 key symbols.)

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson left alter is working for only system default operation not for typing ex. you can not type अ with left alter.

Comment: Do you want that <Left Alt> works the same way as <Right Alt>?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Yes! but No if that left alt key have special features for Ubuntu. I want to know 1)why left alt is not working. 2)Is it assign any special features for Ubuntu? Then 3) How to enable it iff left alt have not assign any special features to Ubuntu. Because In Unity Desktop Left Alt key work like super key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> work the same way as <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> by running this command:

```
setxkbmap -option lv3:lalt_switch
```

But then you'll no longer have access to many shortcuts, so you need to decide which is most important to you.

To change it back you can run:

```
setxkbmap -option
```

(or relogin/reboot).

Comment: plz give more info about that shortcut.

Comment: And also give details about retain same setting back.

Comment: @MadhavNikam: I edited the answer. If you wonder about shortcuts available in Ubuntu, that would be another question.